# I have a Regular Expression problem with winform

Tags: c#

```
Regex.IsMatch(insertSubTitleTextBox.Text, @"^([^=[ ] ])$"))
```

How can I use Regex.IsMatch to judge if user print = or [ or ] in winform, then I show can't use '=' '[' or ']' message

Comment: `[]` are special characters for regex you need to escape them with `\\`

Comment: But I use Regex.IsMatch(insertValueTextBox.Text, @"^([^\=\[\] ])$") can't work

Comment: you should not esape the `=`, but the brackets: `^([^=\[\]])$")`

Comment: ^([^=\[\]])$") can;t work for me

Comment: Start by reading the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-blockquotes) how to format questions and comments.